# Knee of my Character doesn´t bend

Tags: rigging

I am pretty new to rigging so this might be a stupid question. I rigged my simple character including IK constraints and have the problem that the knee isn`t bending when i move the torso down.
[image: Straight legs]
[image: bend legs]

Comment: hello, have you parented With Automatic Weights? Please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the link to the Blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=yrx4ag3A" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/yrx4ag3A/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with your topology, first make the Mirror invisible, you'll see that you have inner faces, select one and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Normal*, and delete the selected faces:

[image]

Also remove all the faces that are close to the mirror axis, it looks like the topology is very dense here:

[image]

Once done, activate the *Mirror* again, enable its *Clipping* option, move the mesh towards the axis to stick the vertices:

[image]

Parent *With Automatic Weights*, it works:

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much !!!